# Calling a function with two same arguments, but setting the second while calling

Tags: dart

I am calling a function that expects two arguments. I use the same variable, but at the second argument I set this variable to another thing.
See below:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2156442de07f56d90b430bc67f3461ac

```
void main() {
  String s = 'oi';

  aa(s, s = 'oi2');
}
void aa(String buf, String buf2){
  print('$buf, $buf2');
}
```

This will print "oi, oi2". 
I want this to happen. I am using a modified notification within properties, like:

```
set title(String n) {
    this.modified('title', _title, _title = n);
}
```

However, I wonder if this can be seen as a bug or it is expected.

thanks, Joe

Comment: I don't get how the `title` getter is involved or what the expected behavior is?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the getter is just a title => _title. The point is, when I call aa(_title = 'oi', _title = 'something else'), within aa the first argument is 'oi' and the second is 'something else', but they are both _title in the caller scope. I guess this is alright, right?

Comment: It's a bit confusing because you use `s` instead of `title` in the question. So is this why the first parameter doesn't also have the `oi2` value assigned inside `aa()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is a `String` which are passed by value, not by reference.

```
aa(s, s = 'oi2');
```

evaluates the first parameter `s`, which is `'oi'`
next `s = 'oi2'` is evaluated, which means `s` gets `'oi2'` assigned
then the result of `s = 'oi2'` (which is `'oi2'`) is passed as 2nd parameter.

After `aa(s, s = 'oi2');` `s` has the value `oi2`.

See also https://gist.github.com/floitschG/b278ada0316dca96e78c1498d15a2bb9

Comment: I thought that the processor would parse all values and then call the function, making both arguments the same. I will use this and save one line of code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation order of arguments is left-to-right, so you can rely on the first  argument's value being found by evaluation `s` to `"ii"`, and then second argument's value is the value of the assignment `s = 'oi2` - which evaluates to `"oi2"` (and not, technically, by reading the variable, it just happens that the variable is written to with the same value before the function is called).

It is expected - if any implementation does something else, it's broken.